# When the value of variables declared const is fixed?

Tags: c++

I think the value of variables declared `const` could be ***either*** fixed after compiling ***or*** fixed when compiling,e.g:

```
//fixed after compiling
const int foo_size{vector_foo.size()};

//fixed when compiling
const int size = 10;
int arr[size];
```

Am I right?

I hope somebody could give a detailed explanation.

Comment: Yes. The second one is a compile-time constant, implicitly `constexpr`. The first one is not.

Comment: Semantically, `const` is always the same with the exception of integral types with constant initializers, which means `constexpr`. This is a legacy feature from before `constexpr` was invented.